# How to properly perform Bonferroni Correction with multiple datasets and questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

Assume I have 6 algorithms, A, B, C, D, E, F and I want to perform a series of tests to see where A outperforms the others and B outperforms the others. In this case, I have 9 hypotheses I am testing:

```
A > B
A > C
A > D
A > E
A > F

B > C
B > D
B > E 
B > F
```

Assume also that I am testing a different set of algorithms (G H and I) on a different dataset,  and I want to test whether G is better than the other two:

```
G > H
G > I
```

In these cases if I wished to perform a Bonferroni correction on the p-values, how many tests am I performing? Do I count all possible tests in the entire study, leading to n=12, or do I restrict it to the individual questions being asked, such as n=9 for the first section and n=2 for the second, or even 5 and 4 for the first and 2 for the second?

Comment: As a heads up, Bonferroni is going to kill your power to detect differences. In fact, Bonferroni is considered an *inadmissible* method, in that, in some sense, Bonferroni-Holm is sometimes better and never worse (except for the simplicity of the calculation, which might be part of your consideration). There are other methods, too. (I think Bonferroni-Holm is inadmissible, too, though I do not know offhand what beats it.)

Comment: Step-down methods that account for correlation structures are uniformly more powerful than Bonferroni-Holm.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to test *both* A > B and B > A, which are contradictory hypotheses? Moreover, a necessary condition for A outperporming the others is that its performance measure is the greatest. If this is the case, why would you want to test B > A?

Comment: Apologies, that was a mistake on my part, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using a Bonferroni correction. You have 11 hypothesis tests. Assuming you're using an $\alpha = 0.05$, you need a p-value of less than $\frac{0.05}{11} \approx 0.0045$ to reject each hypothesis. You will have low statistical power to detect any difference

A [Holm-Bonferroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) correction will always be more powerful than a Bonferroni correction. Holm-Bonferroni is [implemented in base R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) so it should be straightforward to use. I'm sure it's implemented in other statistical software too.

If there is a hierarchy to your hypothesis tests, you can use that to increase your power. It looks like you establish that A is the best algorithm, then establish B is the second-best, and finally see if G is better than H. You can [gate hypothesis tests](https://web.njit.edu/%7Ewguo/Math654_2012/DTB_Chapter5.pdf) of B and G behind A. You would start by establishing A is better than all other algorithms, then only move on to the B hypothesis tests if all of the tests involving A pass. Then you move on to G if you can reject all tests involving B. You can combine this with the Holm-Bonferroni procedure within each gate for better power. [Bretz et. al](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/sim.3495) have a popular method to visualize multiple hypothesis tests with a graph, which can be implemented by with their R package, gMCP.